# Run time error 13 when checkbox is not selected

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple VBA Macro Application.

Three checkboxes, each with a corresponding combobox next to them. The comboboxes contain the numeric values 0 through 4, and enable only when the corresponding checkbox is clicked.

I get a `run time error 13, type mismatch`. I used `if` statement in my code.

I tried to use the `if elseif` method but nothing happens.

```
Private Sub cmdSave_Click()
    Dim wks As Worksheet Dim AddNew As Range
    Set wks = Sheet1 Set AddNew = wks.Range("A65356").End(xlUp).Offset(1,0)
    If chkApple.Enabled = True Then
        AddNew.Offset(0, 0).Value = 20 * cmbApple.Value
    End If
    If chkBanana.Enabled = True Then
        AddNew.Offset(0, 1).Value = 10 * cmbBanana.Value
    End If
    If chkPeers.Enabled = True Then
        AddNew.Offset(0, 2).Value = 30 * cmbPeers.Value
    End If
End Sub

Run Time Error 13
Type Mismatch
```

[image]

Comment: Not a solution but should that be ***PEARS*** rather than peers?

Comment: I don't know why it gives error. The third if statement should not be read since chkPeers is disabled, right..

Comment: Well, first you want to use `Checked = True` rather than `Enabled = True`. Then you want to make sure that an item has actually been selected in the combobox before trying to use its value. Then, you need to remember that comboboxes display text, not numbers, so you need to convert the value of the combobox first. Once you've done those things, then you want to notice that the error happens on a specific line of code, and that stepping through the code up to that point in the debugger can usually help you figure out these sorts of problem.

Comment: Clever use of animated GIF by the way.

Comment: BambooFox, I've reverted your changes since it's not really considered "kosher" to make changes in questions that invalidate otherwise correct answers. The correct thing to do is to either ask another question or, in the case where the suggested answer didn't quite work, leave a comment on the answer. As it turns out, it was the latter case here, my answer (while good for VB) was not not correct for VBA. I've updated it with the correct answer, let me know if there are any other issues (preferably via comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should be using the `Enabled` property for trying to detect if a checkbox is checked. They are *enabled* whenever you're allowed to change them (which should probably be *all* the time in your scenario).

Since yours is always enabled, it's running the line:

```
 AddNew.Offset(0, 2).Value = 30 * cmbPeers.Value
```

and, as `cmbPeers` is empty, it rightly complains about the expression.

If a checkbox is checked, its `value` property will be true. So rather than:

```
If chkApple.Enabled = True Then
```

you should have:

```
If chkApple.Value Then
```

Comment: @ paxdiablo i updated my post with new gif..please see..still getting another error.

Comment: @BambooFox: Everything asked on this site has to stay on this site. Asking for personal help via email is a violation of this site's policies. If you want personalized help off-site, hire a contractor to provide it.

Comment: @Bamboo, sure, send it through with a cheque for AUD150, my going rate is AUD50/hr with minimum three hours :-) On a less jocular note, no, that's not really  how things are done here. For a start, my advice here is free because I enjoy (1) helping people; and (2) foisting my opinions on others :-) Secondly, SO stuff is meant to be a repository for information relevant to future developers as well, something that's rather nullified if help sessions are done external to the site. All you need to for this issue is to use `value` instead of `enabled`.

Comment: @paxdiablo i followed what you said..if chkApple.value instead of chkApple.checked now it's workking.